# JSON array stores previous data result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So my problem is during the first try of updating my profile, it is okay. It outputs one message, and one result only. However, on the second try, it outputs two messages and two results. I have already cleared my array thinking that it was the one that stored the previous result but it did nothing at all.

in my js file is the following:

```
$('#edit_my_profile').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var fname = $('#my_profile_fname').val(),
      mname = $('#my_profile_mname').val(),
      lname = $('#my_profile_lname').val(),
      user_number = $('#my_profile_user_number').val(),
      parent_number = $('#my_profile_parent_number').val(),
      department = $('#my_profile_department').val(),
      course = $('#my_profile_course').val(),
      year_level = $('#my_profile_year').val(),
      section = $('#my_profile_section').val(),
      username = $('#my_profile_username').val(),
      password = $('#my_profile_password').val(),
      alert = $('#my_profile_message_board');

  if(!validate([fname, mname, lname, user_number, parent_number, department, course, year_level, section, username, password])){
    notify('<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg mr-2"></i> <b>Error!</b> Cannot leave empty fields!', 'danger');
  } else if(password == 'password12345ddd'){
    notify('<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg mr-2"></i> <b>Error!</b> Please change the default password!', 'danger');
  } else{
    var modal = $('#modal_confirm_update_profile');

    modal.modal('show');

    $('#btn_update_profile').on('click', function(){
      modal.modal('hide')
      var data = $('#edit_my_profile').serializeArray();
      data[data.length] = {name : "edit_my_profile", value : 1};

      $.ajax({
        url : controllers('ProfilesController'),
        method : 'POST',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(e){
          // notify(e.message, e.alert);
          // my_profile_information();
          console.log(e)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

and here is my ProfilesController.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_my_profile'])){
    $fname = $init->post('my_profile_fname');
    $mname = $init->post('my_profile_mname');
    $lname = $init->post('my_profile_lname');
    $user_number = $init->post('my_profile_user_number');
    $parent_number = $init->post('my_profile_parent_number');
    $section = $init->post('my_profile_section');
    $username = $init->post('my_profile_username');
    $password = encrypt($init->post('my_profile_password'));
    $updated_at = Carbon::parse($user_updated_at);

    $validate = validate([$fname, $mname, $lname, $user_number, $parent_number, $section, $username, $password]);

    $now = Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString();
    $length_in_days = $updated_at->diffInMinutes($now);

    if($length_in_days < 7){
        $json['bool'] = false;
        $json['alert'] = 'danger';
        $json['message'] = "<b>Error!</b> Calm down officer! You have recently updated your profile $length_in_days ago!";
    } else{
        if(!$validate){
            $json['bool'] = false;
            $json['alert'] = 'danger';
            $json['message'] = '<b>Error!</b> Cannot leave empty fields!';
        } else{
            $sql = $init->query("UPDATE users SET fname = '$fname', mname = '$mname', lname = '$lname', user_number = '$user_number', parent_number = '$parent_number', section_id = '$section', username = '$username', password = '$password' WHERE student_id = {$_SESSION['student_id']}");

            if($sql){
                $json['bool'] = true;
                $json['alert'] = 'primary';
                $json['message'] = '<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-lg fa-spin"></i> Successfully updated your profile!';
            } else{
                $json['bool'] = false;
                $json['alert'] = 'danger';
                $json['message'] = '<b>Error!</b> Something went wrong!';
            }
        }
    }

    $json['error'] = $init->error();
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

and the result during my second try, is this(chrome's console):

```
{bool: false, alert: "danger", message: "<b>Error!</b> Calm down officer! You have recently updated your profile 5 ago!", error: ""}
{bool: false, alert: "danger", message: "<b>Error!</b> Calm down officer! You have recently updated your profile 5 ago!", error: ""}
{bool: false, alert: "danger", message: "<b>Error!</b> Calm down officer! You have recently updated your profile 5 ago!", error: ""}
```

It should only output one.

Comment: The issue is because you're adding a new `click` event handler every time the form is `submit`. Move the `click` handler outside the `submit`

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you sir. It is right :D Thank youu!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from adding the `click` listener to `#btn_update_profile` *inside* your `submit` listener. Every time the form gets submitted, the button gets told to call a new function when it's clicked, which is why the second submit sends the POST request twice and why you're seeing two logs in the console.

Assuming that `#btn_update_profile` is inside your modal, change your code so that you only add the `click` listener once, and inside of that listener you can check a variable to see if the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime `$('#edit_my_profile').on('submit',...)` is called it would reaply the JSON call n times.
Just take `$('#btn_update_profile').on('click',...)` Out of it, like this:

```
var modal = $('#modal_confirm_update_profile');
$('#edit_my_profile').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var fname = $('#my_profile_fname').val(),
      mname = $('#my_profile_mname').val(),
      lname = $('#my_profile_lname').val(),
      user_number = $('#my_profile_user_number').val(),
      parent_number = $('#my_profile_parent_number').val(),
      department = $('#my_profile_department').val(),
      course = $('#my_profile_course').val(),
      year_level = $('#my_profile_year').val(),
      section = $('#my_profile_section').val(),
      username = $('#my_profile_username').val(),
      password = $('#my_profile_password').val(),
      alert = $('#my_profile_message_board');

  if(!validate([fname, mname, lname, user_number, parent_number, department, course, year_level, section, username, password])){
    notify('<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg mr-2"></i> <b>Error!</b> Cannot leave empty fields!', 'danger');
  } else if(password == 'password12345ddd'){
    notify('<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg mr-2"></i> <b>Error!</b> Please change the default password!', 'danger');
  } else {
    modal.modal('show');
  }
});
$('#btn_update_profile').on('click', function() {
  modal.modal('hide')
  var data = $('#edit_my_profile').serializeArray();
  data[data.length] = {name : "edit_my_profile", value : 1};
  $.ajax({
    url : controllers('ProfilesController'),
    method : 'POST',
    data : data,
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(e){
      // notify(e.message, e.alert);
      // my_profile_information();
      console.log(e)
    }
  });
});
```